# SharePoint online remote event receivers without Azure Service bus connector

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I want my SP 2013 cloud app (office 365) to connect to my on premises WCF services. Visual Studio gives templates to create provider hosted apps for this purpose. However, that requires Windows Azure service bus connector that helps the app connect to WCF. Since I have a static IP, I want to get this done without the connector.

I attempted this by implementing IRemoteEventService in a new WCF with wsHTTPBinding with security as none. This is running on static IP machine with all connections allowed on the port where this service is listening. I was able to call this service from my test WCF client over the internet.

Now in my app, I changed my end point to this WCF service. When app installs it tries to call this end point to deliver the app install event. However, it gives error that end point is not available or there is a soap error.

Please provide pointers on what changes are required in WCF configuration to receive calls from SharePoint. Thanks.